# Fellow user started fighting verbally when incorrect answer was downvoted

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I downvoted an answer which was wrong as it will give the same error which answer-er described in his post that this thing was wrong with OP's code.
I commented and told him his mistake and then he literally took it to fighting level and also downvoted my previous questions and answers just to take revenge from me.

Here is the link of that question:
[Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686248/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v7/36686326#36686326).
See the **unedited version** of that answer and it was incorrect as the version that he pointed out is also unavailable so I downvoted and commented what's wrong. See his comments that how he has taken that comment in consideration. 
Isn't that to be considered rude. This kind of behaviour by users gives encourage **anonymous voting** behaviour as neither I have commented on that nor that fight would break up.

Comment: Downvoting is the correct approach for an incorrect/bad answer. Even better, you left a comment as to *why* you downvoted. If this happens in the future, simply flag for a moderator and move on. You don't owe the answerer anything, and you certainly are not required to fix their solution.

Comment: And people wonder why we don't want forced comments... One way to try to avoid this is to comment some time before or after, to reduce the timing correlation. I also tend to remind users that voting is anonymous when I see such claims, regardless if I voted or not.

Comment: He has also downvoted my previous answer just to take revenge for his reputation loss

Comment: Well, unless its done serially, downvoting isn't an actionable offense. None of this is even worth your time to worry about.

Comment: Main point of my discussion is to point out the fact that this kind of behaviour will encourage anonymous votings and this will not be helpful for community

Comment: Voting is anonymous by design. You clearly don't agree with that design choice (from many of your postings on meta), but that doesn't make the design wrong.

Comment: @TZHX yes I earlier use to disagree with this but after seeing many people  behaviour now I understand why it has been made like this and completely agree with this

Comment: @CodeCaster what does anonymous voting means then?

Comment: Just that: nobody can see who voted on what. Leaving a comment before or after you voted is something different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best course of action would've been not to reply to the OP of that answer.
If necessary, you could have flagged the comment as "not constructive", or even "rude".

There will always be users that don't appreciate your input.

Comment: I marked one of the comment as rude and it got deleted too as that was way too harsh

Comment: I got the impression that was the case, yea. A couple of comments appear to be missing. Flagging was the right thing to do.

Comment: This has happened me quite few times in past. Meanwhile I was commenting someone else downvoted their question/answer and they start fighting with me that why I downvoted. They are just too obsessed with reputation points

Comment: _"@SomeUser: Please keep in mind that voting is anonymous. Users can't see who voted on their posts."_ Reminding them of that can help.

Comment: I know but downvote came as soon as I comment so they starts fighting

Comment: Remind them voting is anonymous (once). If they keep arguing, ignore and move on.

Comment: yes that's only thing left to do for this kind of behaviour `IGNORE AND MOVE ON`

Answer (score 8):

Do not engage. If you encounter rude or unconstructive comments, flag them. You have the right to vote as you please, and do not have the obligation to edit the answer instead. Don't waste your time having this discussion with other users. Simply move on.